# Prove that in a $4n$-gon, every other diagonal passes through a common point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

> Suppose two regular $2n$-gons in the plane, which interesect one another to form a  $4n$-gon. Prove that every other diagonal of this $4n$-gon, i.e. $P_{1}P_{2n+1},P_{3}P_{2n+3},...,P_{2n-1}P_{4n-1}$ passes through a common point with every other.

A $4n$-gon has an even number of sides, so the diagonals of a regular $4n$-gon all meet in a single point. We can obtain a regular polygon easily by using e.g. two congruent polygons rotated by $ 45^{\circ}$ and this fulfills the condition. Even if the resulting polygon is not regular, it should hold (for every other diagonal). In all examples I attempted this is the case, but I had trouble proving it.
I'll be glad to hear your ideas.

Comment: Isn’t this immediate? If the $4n$-gon is assumed to be the intersection of two regular $2n$-gons, then every other diagonal are just the diagonals of one of the $2n$-gons… Or are you claiming it holds for any $4n$-gon?

Comment: Are you assuming that the 4n-gon is regular? (It is stated in the question for the 2n-gons, but not the 4n-gon)

Comment: @Milten I believe the first part requires "regular 4n-gon" as it's clearly not true for an arbitrary 4n-gon. For the second part, it doesn't require that the two polygons have the same center, or even the same size.  With a certain interpretation of how to order the $P_i$ are (since it's not defined), the statement can be shown to be true.  EG The "intersect one another to form a 4n-gon" definately needs clarifying. Can they polygons intersect only at a corner? I suspect they want that every edge of a 2n-gon intersects another edge of the other 2n-gon.

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh, I was having trouble parsing the question, since the first statement is clearly false as it is. I think you may be right, in that it has a missing word... Alternatively, the first sentence should not be there at all...

Comment: The first sentence is simply the title. The $2n$-gons are indeed regular, but the $4n$-gons created by the intersectio need not be. Altough they can, and that would render the veracity of the claim trivial, as I stated in the question.

Comment: @fayog Then you should likely delete the first line in the writeup, which is adding confusion to the reader. The problem should just be "Suppose two regular ... prove that every diagonal ....". $\quad$ Can you also include an image to explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer.
It is a writeup with an image to explain what is confusing about the question (but couldn't be fit into a comment).

1. Based on my interpretation of OP's comment, I read the question as

> Suppose two regular $2n$-gons in the plane, which interesect one
> another to form a  $4n$-gon. Prove that every other diagonal of this
> $4n$-gon, i.e. $P_{1}P_{2n+1},P_{3}P_{2n+3},...,P_{2n-1}P_{4n-1}$
> passes through a common point with every other.

This edit was not made by the OP, other than saying "the first sentence is simply the title".
2. Clarity on how the intersection happens is needed.

- When two regular 2n-gons intersect, with each edge cutting an edge of the other polygon, it results in a 8n-gon, not a 4n-gon.
- If the 2n-gons intersect with vertices contained without another, then we will not end up with 4n vertices.
- It's not clear to me how they want to get a polygon with 4n vertices (based on the labelling) and 4n edges (based on the name of the 4n-gon).

3. Relatedly, clarity on how to label the vertices would be helpful.
4. If the two regular 2n-gons do not have the same center, then the diagonals will not pass through a common point.

[image]

Comment: My interpretation is that the $4n$-gon is supposed to be the polygon with vertices $[123456781]$ in your illustration. The sets of digaonals are then $\{15, 37\}$ and $\{26, 48\}$. Each set meets in a common point (though not the same as each other). This is the only way I can see the statement to be true, but at the same time it makes the problem very easy, so I might be wrong,

Comment: @Milten 1) But this polygon has 16 vertices, with the other 8 arising from the intersection of the edges.  That's what I'm seeking clarification on. Perhaps we are supposed to look at the convex hull? 2) With your interpretation of sets, the conclusion is trivial only provided we prove that "the only way to get all 4n vertices to land on the outside is by forcing every edge to intersect 1 other edge" (which is how this picture is presented).  3) OP states "In all examples I attempted this is the case", so I'd like to know if they considered my case.

Comment: I agree with your points. I made my assumptions based on how to make statement true. If we consider a polygon as the set of vertices, my interpretation is a bit more justified; the union then has $4n$ vertices for example (ignoring the case of coinciding vertices). But let's not debate this anymore, since the two of us seem to be on the same page anyways. We should just see if OP clarifies.